# Blogger images simplify hover over text code

Tags: html, css, hover, blogger, jquery-hover

I want to create a blog page full of images that have text appear over them when hovered over. I'm using blogger.com.

I'd like to have it appear like the Tiger (Image Hover Overlay) in this post: http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html

or the Waterfall (Displaying Text) in this post: http://www.gadgetronicx.com/p/blog-page_9.html

- I'm not very good with html but is there a way I don't have to repeat
  the same code for every image?
- How can I center the image on the page?
- How can I get two images on the same line?

Comment: show your code. so that we can give our idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not very good with html but is there a way I don't have to repeat the same code for every image?
2. How can I center the image on the page?
3. How can I get two images on the same line?

For simple answers for the above questions:

1. Yes. No need to write for every image. You can use  like below. Assume all your images comes under the div with id called "divmainid".

   ```
    #divmainid img
    {
      #image styles are goes here.
    }
   ```
2. You can use "text-align:center" or "margin:0px auto" for the div area.
3. Many ways you can do. Simple way is assign "display:inline-block" for the div around your images.